# Blurry Saved Images of Detected Objects using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ar.drone

I have a c++ code that is being run on the Parrot AR.Drone version 2.0 to detect objects, then save images of the detected objects to the controller (computer). As you all may know, the AR.Drone has an 720p High Definition camera. However, the saved images are very blurry. I cannot seem to find any OpenCV function that increases the resolution of the saved images, however I believe the resolution is set to 95/100 by default for OpenCV. Does anyone know of any solution to this problem?

Any input or comment would be helpful.

Comment: Are you looking for deblurring (remove blur) or upscaling (increase resolution)?
what do you mean by "resolution is set to 95/100"

Comment: Increase resolution. I read somewhere that OpenCV, by default, sets the resolution of saved images to 95 on a range that has a maximum of 100. I am assuming you ask that question because that is incorrect information, right?

Comment: resolution isnt changed automatically. If you observe too small images there is probably some rescaling happening in your code. This could explain the blur because rescalung includes interpolation.

Comment: You could put in a 4K sensor, that still wouldn't give you sharp images. Image quality is determined by a whole set of factors, sensor resolution being the least important nowadays. (It's generally good enough). In particular, drones can't handle a lot of weight while good lenses and mechanical image stabilization systems are heavy.

Comment: Can you include an example of the images you're seeing in your question?  The 720p camera is a little blurry no matter what you do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean 95/100 of jPEG quality. You can change the third parameter of `cv::imwrite` like it said in the [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite)

```
cv::imwrite("name.jpg", image, CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY=100); //100 instead of default 95
```

But this method only increase the quality, not the resolution... and there shouldn't be much difference between 95 and 100%.

Comment: Or save in png (if jpeg is the issue here)

Comment: Unlikely - a lower JPEG quality causes block artifacts, not blurring.

Comment: Yes, I don't think that changing the third parameter will make much of a difference. I also did save the images in JPEG format, I did not think that picture formats could impact quality of images. I will try to save images in PNG format and see if that helps. Other than the PNG format, are there any others that you would recommend?

Comment: Are you sure the image degrades when you save it? Do you see it well with `imshow` just before write it?